# Is there a chromeless (no UI) Flash video player?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, video

I'm trying to develop a unified video player, with a single standards-based UI that interfaces via JS to either a HTML5 `<video>` element or a "dumb", chromeless Flash player.

This Flash player would probably be implemented with the [`VideoDisplay` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VideoDisplay.html).

The only requirement besides playing AVC/MP4 videos is that it would have a JavaScript interface for methods (play, pause, seek) and events (onPlay, onPause, onTimeUpdate). Extra points if it mimics the `<video>` interface.

Does such a player exist? I assumed it would be easy to find, but I've been googling for longer than I care to admit, and I've clicked every link in the "Similar Questions" sidebar (on the "Ask Question" page). If I were a competent Flash developer, I'd certainly do it myself, but I'm trying not to invest time learning Flash/AS.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [mediaelementjs.com](http://mediaelementjs.com/). Note that they do provide a player UI (built w/ DOM elements & CSS), but read down the page — it's also designed to be used without their player, as an object that will simply provide a Flash (or Silverlight) instance when HTML5 media elements aren't available (due to either the browser itself or just the codec support), and it does mimic the HTML5 media element APIs as you were hoping for.

It's not perfect (preload handling is kind of wonky across browsers & plugin fallback scenarios, in my experience, for example) but it's solid overall and sounds like it might be exactly what you're looking for.

Oh, and the means of getting to fullscreen when you're in plugin/fallback mode is annoying, but it's not the developer's fault... JavaScript is not allowed to send Flash or Silverlight to full screen, period, as a security restriction. So instead the JS setFullscreen command just forces the plugin to reveal a "Go Fullscreen" button in the upper right corner of the plugin instance. If you don't care to offer the fullscreen option, though, it's a non-issue.

Comment: Yes! This is perfect, thank you. (And your answer came just as I was reluctantly opening Flash CS4.)

Comment: Argh. The two-step "Go Fullscreen" button is really aggravating, as you say. You didn't by chance come up with a more elegant solution?

Comment: Well, I was implementing a player with a very custom UI where the fullscreen button is completely detached from the toolbar. So I modified the Flash and Silverlight source make the Go Fullscreen button match my DOM control, position in the right place relative to my DOM controls, and stay visible all the time. So that's pretty seamless, and it was only a half-day to a day of work, but I think it'd be much harder to do with a design that doesn't isolate the fullscreen button.

Answer (score 0):

I would try http://flowplayer.org/ you can control it with JS its really simple, it can also convert html5 video tags into flash if the browser does not support html5,

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I'm looking for something extremely lightweight, though. I'm already using JW Player, which is too rigid and too bloated for my purposes. Basically, I want to build everything myself *except* for the Flash player and JS event/method interface.